# Why is window.outerHeight !== $(window).outerHeight()

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

Console Log:

```
window.outerHeight
> 1080
$(window).height()
> 1008
$(window).outerHeight()
> 1008
```

What I really want is a cross-browser solution for window.outerHeight and I thought that jQuery had that. Why is it delivering a different window outer height ? It looks to me that jQuery is calculating the viewport size instead ?

The reason I care is mostly because I dont' think IE8 has "window.outerHeight"

Comment: jQuery documentation says "This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use .height() instead"

Comment: @Thilo: That's an answer. :-)

Comment: But the documentation of `.height()` says that for the window, it returns the viewport size.

Comment: "What I really want is a cross-browser solution for window.outerHeight and I thought that jQuery had that. " Apparently not, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IE8 Try using:

```
document.body.offsetHeight
```

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14077446/864385
Not sure if this approach would actually work and how accurate it is.

Comment: So the real solution would be to use `window_height = window.outerHeight || document.body.offsetHeight;` ?

Comment: @Norris Yes, you should try that out.